# Office add-in and Ribbon: initialization order?

Tags: .net, ms-office, add-in

What is initialization order of add-in and Ribbon? Is add-in object always created before Ribbon, or this can vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ribbon is created by calling the addin object's `RequestService` method for an `IRibbonExtensibility` implementation.
Thus, the addin must already exist.

In Ribbon XML templates, you can these this in the Ribbon CS file:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn {
    private RibbonManager ribbon;
    ///<summary>Returns an object that extends a feature in the 2007 Microsoft Office system.</summary>
    ///<param name="serviceGuid">A System.Guid that identifies an extensibility interface 
    ///that is supported by applications in the 2007 Microsoft Office system.</param>
    ///<returns>An object that implements the extensibility interface that is identified by serviceGuid.</returns>
    protected override object RequestService(Guid serviceGuid) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(JournalPath) && serviceGuid == typeof(IRibbonExtensibility).GUID) {
            if (ribbon == null)
                ribbon = new RibbonManager();
            return ribbon;
        }

        return base.RequestService(serviceGuid);
    }
}
```